# can we change the logging level of log4j at runtime

Tags: java, logging, log4j

i have an issue, i want to change the logging level of log4j at runtime, i have tried many things with log4j.properties file, i have also tried to written a code which after particular time again reads the properties file and again configure the logger.

but the problem is, i want to change the logging level to DEBUG for one API call, and then when that call is completed, the logger should again change to the previous value..

please help..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Calling the [`Logger.setLevel`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level)) method with the desired [`Level`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) can alter a `Logger`'s output level at runtime.

The following is an example which demonstrates its usage:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
logger.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new SimpleLayout()));

System.out.println("*** The current level will be INFO");

logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
logger.warn("Only INFO and higher will appear");
logger.info("Only INFO and higher will appear");
logger.debug("Only INFO and higher will appear");

System.out.println("*** Changing level to DEBUG");

// remember the previous level
Level previousLevel = logger.getLevel();

logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
logger.warn("DEBUG and higher will appear");
logger.info("DEBUG and higher will appear");
logger.debug("DEBUG and higher will appear");

System.out.println("*** Changing level back to previous level");

// revert to previous level
logger.setLevel(previousLevel);
logger.warn("Only INFO and higher will appear");
logger.info("Only INFO and higher will appear");
logger.debug("Only INFO and higher will appear");
```

The above outputs:

```
*** The current level will be INFO
WARN - Only INFO and higher will appear
INFO - Only INFO and higher will appear
*** Changing level to DEBUG
WARN - DEBUG and higher will appear
INFO - DEBUG and higher will appear
DEBUG - DEBUG and higher will appear
*** Changing level back to previous level
WARN - Only INFO and higher will appear
INFO - Only INFO and higher will appear
```

The above demonstrates how to change the level of one `Logger` named `myLogger`, but if the levels of all the loggers in the current repository should be changed, then the `setLevel` method on the *root logger* obtained by [`Logger.getRootLogger`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html#getRootLogger()) should be called to change the levels on all the child loggers.

Answer (score 9):

The log level of a logger can be changed by calling `setLevel` as described by @coobird.  However, there is a catch!

When you call `getLogger(name)`, the logging library will return you an existing `Logger` object if possible.  If two or more threads request a logger with the same name, they will get the same object.  If one of the threads calls `setLevel`, this will change the logger level for all of the others.  That can lead to unexpected behavior.

If you really need to do this kind of thing, a better approach would be to create a logger with a different name for the case where you want to logging at a different level.

However, I'm not convinced of the wisdom of the application calling `setLevel` at all.  The `setLevel` method is about filtering the log messages, and you should not be wresting control of logging filtering away from the user / deployer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes sense to call `setLevel` if a server has a "Controller" thread. That way, you can dynamically change logging level at runtime to debug an issue, and change it back when you are done.

But I don't know what happens when it is called from a separate thread.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Try answering questions you DO know the answer to in order to be able to make comments!

Answer (score 0):

setLevel method is there only for java.util.logging.Logger and not for org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger

This is how we set log level in apache log4j

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration
conf = ctx.getConfiguration();
conf.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
ctx.updateLoggers(conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot (1.5+), [you can use logger endpoint to POST desired logging level](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-logger-configuration).