# Dynamic Apache log4j in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j

I have a Spring 3.1 MVC web application running on Tomcat 7 with Java 7. I have a really simple logging set up right now. I am using a `logging.xml` config file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" /> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n" /> 
        </layout> 
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.jasper">
        <level value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.catalina">
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
    </logger>

    <root> 
        <priority value ="info" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

In my code, I do this:

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogget (ClassName.class);
log.info ("Info Message");
```

What I am looking to do right now is be able to change the logging level on the fly, without restarting the Tomcat container. I am looking for Java code that I can put in an MVC controller and expose to certain users in my web application. I know there's a lot out there, I'm looking for a link that you think will work for me. As you can see, my logging is very simple, I don't fully understand this stuff, so I'm not sure what is going to work for me, or even where to start. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the solution described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415467/can-we-change-the-logging-level-of-log4j-at-runtime) is the one you were looking for?

Comment: No problem, even though at least 50% of the credit belongs to "coobird" who answered the original post.

Comment: I don't disagree, but you get the rep, congrats!